# Как подать напряжение к pin'у другой Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, микроконтроллеры

Есть две Arduino Mega 2560, соединенные между собой через TX и RX. Ко второй Arduino нет доступа по USB, только через первую Arduino. К 3 pin'у второй Arduino подключено реле. Как можно подать питание с первой Arduino на 3 pin второй Arduino программно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно внести в протокол верхнего уровня UART команду управления пином. Второй Ардуино должен принимать запросы первого, распознавать команду и определить, что нужно сейчас делать: подать напряжение на 3-й пин, убрать напряжение с 3-го пина или выполнить иные действия, описанные в протоколе.

Кстати, термин "подать питание" здесь не совсем правильный. Когда речь идёт о GPIO, лучше говорить "подать логическую единицу" или "подать логический ноль". Питание - это аналоговая цепь с большим током, GPIO - цифровая цепь с очень маленьким током.

Comment: Я в электротехнике новичок, поэтому некоторые термины могу употребить неправильно :)
Дело в том, что во второй Arduino не получится залить скетч :/ Можно как-нибудь обойтись без этого?

Comment: Скетч - это прошивка? Если да, то, скорее всего, никак. Я не работал с Ардуино, но в микроконтроллерах только программа может управлять пинами. Нет программы - некому управлять. Но если не получается прошить его обычными средствами, стоит исследовать возможность использования UART-загрузчика. Нужно проверить, существует ли он вообще на вашем контроллере, и если есть, то прошить его через UART. Иных вариантов я не вижу.

Comment: нет, это не прошивка, обычная программа. Понял, спасибо большое за ответ